# How to conditionally remove first N rows of a dataframe out of 2 dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes as following:

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'col2': ["2010-01-01", "2011-01-01", "2012-01-01", "2013-01-01"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df

    col1    col2
0   1       2010-01-01
1   2       2011-01-01
2   3       2012-01-01
3   4       2013-01-01
```

The other dataframe may look like the following:

```
d2 = {'col1': [11, 22, 33, 44], 'col1': ["2011-01-01", "2011-05-01", "2012-02-01", "2012-06-01"]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
df2

    col1    col2
0   11      2011-01-01
1   22      2011-05-01
2   33      2012-02-01
3   44      2012-06-01
```

In both dataframes, **col2** includes dates (in String format, not as a date object) and these dates are placed in ascending order.

In my use case, both of these dataframes are supposed to start with the same value in **col2**.

The first col2 value of **df** is **"2010-01-01"**.
The first col2 value of **df2** is **"2011-01-01"**.
In this particular example, since **"2010-01-01"** does not exist in **df2** and **"2011-01-01"** is the second row item of col2 in **df** dataframe, the first row of **df** needs to be removed so that both dataframes start with the same date String value in **col2**. So, df is supposed to look as following after the change:

```
    col1    col2
1   2       2011-01-01
2   3       2012-01-01
3   4       2013-01-01
```

(Please note that the index is not reset after the change.)

But, this could have been the opposite and we could need to remove row(s) from df2 instead to be able to make these dataframes start with the same value in col2.

And in some cases, we may need to remove multiple rows, not only 1, from the dataframe where we need to remove the rows in case we do not find the match in the second row.

Corner case handling:
The logic should also handle such cases (without throwing errors) where it is not possible to make these 2 dataframes start with the same col2 value, in case there is no match. In that case, all rows from both dataframes are supposed to be removed.

Is there an elegant way of developing this logic without writing too many lines of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get minimal `datetime` in both DataFrames and then filter all rows after this row in both `DataFrame`s (because is possible some rows are removed from `df1` or `df2`) by compare values by `both` and [`Series.cummax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cummax.html). If no match both DataFrames are empty.

```
both = df.merge(df2, on='col2')['col2'].min()
df = df[df['col2'].eq(both).cummax()]
print (df)
   col1        col2
1     2  2011-01-01
2     3  2012-01-01
3     4  2013-01-01

df2 = df2[df2['col2'].eq(both).cummax()]
print (df2)
   col1        col2
0    11  2011-01-01
1    22  2011-05-01
2    33  2012-02-01
3    44  2013-01-01
```

---

```
#no match df2.col2 in df.col2
d2 = {'col1': [11, 22, 33, 44], 'col2': ["2011-01-21", "2011-05-01",
                                         "2012-02-01", "2003-01-01"]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)


both = df.merge(df2, on='col2')['col2'].min()
df = df[df['col2'].eq(both).cummax()]
print (df)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [col1, col2]
Index: []

df2 = df2[df2['col2'].eq(both).cummax()]
print (df2)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [col1, col2]
Index: []
```